# Gamma correction formula

Tags: image-processing, rendering, gamma

In discussion of gamma correction, most people write formula

```
y = 255 (x/255)^gamma
```

I guess this is applied for each channel: R, G and B. My quesion is following

1. shouldn't I rather analyze the image (I assume 8bit per color channel), find the maximum intensity pixel among all channels and then write

   y = x_max (x/x_max)^gamma

?

2. if the answer for part 1. is "yes" then the second question follows: what should I use for x_max for each color channel? should I find a single value x_max for all colors or should I use individual x_max for each color channel, x_max_r, x_max_g and x_max_b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, generally, **no**: you should *not* normalize by the (content dependent) max grayscale value.
The gamma correction is exponential (thus, scale sensitive) and is done on the scale of [0,1].
In the case of 8-bit images, the max (possible) value is 255, so you normalize by `255` to scale the value range to [0,1].